# for loop stops after 2nd case in Selenium

Tags: selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, bots

I am working on a script that should just refresh trades every 15 minutes. It worked well, but then I found a problem. When it finds the trade that has to be refreshed.

```
else if (text[2] == "hours" || text[2] == "hour" || text[2] == "days" || 
text[2] == "day" || text[2] == "month" || text[2] == "months" || x >= 15)
```

It goes into the trade, edits it and saves as it should. But right after that it stops working. It says the program is still running, but nothing happens anymore. I have no idea why it would not work as it works perfectly for this case:

```
if (text[2] == "seconds")
                continue;
```

I can't find a reason for loop to stop working to be honest. Would appreciate any ideas or tips.

Code:

```
    private void CheckItems(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        IList<IWebElement>
            trades = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("rlg-trade-display-header")); // add all trades to list

        for (var i = 0; i <= trades.Count; i++) // loop to check all trades
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(tradeUrl);
            if (i == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Active Trades: " + trades.Count);
            var text = driver
                .FindElement(By.XPath(
                    "/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[4]/div[" + (i + 1) + "]/div[1]/div/div/span"))
                .Text.Split(); // reads text from trade and adjust it for the program
            Console.WriteLine("Trade " + (i + 1) + " was last updated " + text[1] + " " + text[2] + " ago.");

            var x = int.Parse(text[1]); // convert string to int to check time later

            if (text[2] == "seconds")
                continue;


            if (text[2] == "hours" || text[2] == "hour" || text[2] == "days" || text[2] == "day" ||
                text[2] == "month" || text[2] == "months" || x >= 15)
            {
                var element1 =
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[4]/div[" + (i + 1) +
                                                "]/div[1]/a/div"));
                var actions1 = new Actions(driver);
                actions1.MoveToElement(element1).Click().Perform(); // scrolls down to choosen element and clicks it


                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[2]/a[1]"))
                    .Click(); // click choosen element


                var element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnSubmit"));
                var actions = new Actions(driver);
                actions.MoveToElement(element).Click().Perform(); // scrolls down to choosen element and clicks it
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bot = new Program();
        bot.setup(bot.driver);

        while (true)
        {
            bot.CheckItems(bot.driver);


            Thread.Sleep(15000); // wait 15 second before next loop
        }
    }
```

What I found out is that when I put a `Console.ReadLine()` in main after `bot.CheckItems(bot.driver);` it will now refresh all the trades and print everything for one whole for loop and then it stops and doesn't continue. And if I keep it like in code I given higher it works perfectly if all trades are in no need for refresh but if even one is it will refresh it and stop working. Any ideas what might be a reason for that problem? And why `Console.ReadLine()` matters?

Comment: This is a tricky one and someone with more knowledge should provide some input. As far as I can see, this should work just fine. Instead of using `==` shouldn't you be using `.contains(" ")`?

Comment: Hmm. I think it doesn't really matter because text[2] is a string so string can == another string. But! I found a fix for now. Basicly what I changed is  I took while (true) loop out from main and poot it over method : CheckItems. And it started to work as it should. Meems like the loop was the problem.. But I have no idea why.

Comment: Well done man. Good luck in the future! Post the answer here for others to see.